# Ruby loop through model and assign a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and trying to write a script which has

```
Departure (date, price, accommodation_start, accommodation_end)
Accommodation (name, price, location)
```

Where Departure has many Accommodations

Task to loop through every departures, if it is departs after 01/July/2000, assign accommodation start and accommodation end to it

Here's the code I have managed to write so far

```
class Departure
  attr_reader :date, :price, :accommodation_start, :accommodation_end

  def initialize()
    @departure = []
  end
end

class Accommodation
  attr_reader :name, :price, :location

  def initialize(name, price, location)
    @name = first
    @price = price
    @location= location
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the initialize Departure should have atributes of Departure as you did on Accomadation but with one @accommodations=[].

Then, you will need have a main class that will have a array of Departures.

Imagining you already created the function to create a new Departure, adding departure in Departures array.

You'll create a function o solve your task, in this function you can make somothing like this:

```
     #a loop for all departures
     @dePartureArray.each do |departure|
          # Here you will compare the dates
          # you can use:
          if Date.parse(departure.date)< Date.parse('2000-07-01')
             departure.addAccommodation( Accommodation.new("theName","ThePrice","location"))
          end
     end
```

I hope this can help you.